# os.path.realpath() returns a string starting with my home:

Tags: python

`os.path.realpath(__file__)`

returns

`/home/toto/file:/home/toto/.config/libreoffice/4/user/uno_packages/cache/uno_packages/lu37847ivic.tmp_/bal-L-1.1.4.oxt/python/rdt_bal.py`

Why is it starting with this `/home/toto/file:` instead of given the expected url which is the part after ':'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`os.path.realpath` will first resolve any symbolic links in the path, and then return the absolute path

Comment: Is there a solution included in path methods that returns only the second part? I tried `os.path.abspath()` that gives the same result.